# How can I make a sap.m.Table sortable by drag and drop?

Tags: drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable, sapui5

I would like to make my sap.m.Table manually sortable, so I can sort the rows of my table by drag and drop. I have tried using the jQueryUI sortable() method (it works on lists!), but if I use it on the table it makes the whole table draggable and if I use it on a ColumnListItem I can sort the content of the ColumnListItem, but not the ColumnListItems listed in the table. Does anybody have an idea what else I could try? Or maybe even have a solution to my problem? 
I am thankful for all the help I can get!

Comment: As of UI5 version 1.54, [drag and drop is now supported](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/85a913571162684284853b79192e7aeba0c3d80a) out of the box. Take a look at [this example](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.TableDnD/preview). In the second table, you can sort items just by dragging.

Comment: For sorting on a single table with multiple item pages using drag and drop, Is there a way that I can hover with a drag item on the pagination button and it takes me to the 2nd items page and I can sort it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you only want to make the table rows (`<tr>`) draggable. Therefore you need to pass the parent element to `jQuery.sortable`. Try something like this in your controller:

```
this.getView().$().find(".sapMList.myClass tbody").sortable();
```

Whereas `myClass` is a style class you added to your control (so that only THIS table instance will be affected).

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me with $('.sortable tbody').sortable();